# Javascript - Remove Seconds and GMT from date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

var date = new Date();

it displays "Sun Jul 16 2017 00:05:50 GMT+0800 (SGT)"

But, I need only "Month date, year hour:minutes am". Please let me know to remove unwanted datas and display them.

Thanks

Comment: `date = date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');`

Comment: If you just want to display dates then the above should be fine. If you want to do some more advanced stuff with with dates then using momentjs library helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for everything concerning dates...
;)

```js
var date = moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY hh:mm A")

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split the string, you can use the arrays splice fn to remove everything from 4 chars before 'GMT' on. Then just join back to a string:

```
var dateArray = date.split('');
dateArray.splice(date.indexOf('GMT') - 4);
var shorter = dateArray.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this function according to your needs:

```
 function formatJSDate()
    {
     return (dt.getMonth() +1 + '/' + dt.getDate() + '/' + dt.getYear() + ' ' + dt.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric',minute:'numeric', hour12: true }));
    }
```

Now you can try this:

```
 var dt = new Date('Sun Jul 16 2017 00:05:50 GMT+0800 (SGT)'); 
//or  var dt= new Date();
    alert(formatJSDate(dt));
```

OUTPUT:

```
7/15/117 9:05 AM
```